# Catching errors from returned promises in Javascirpt

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, promise, async-await

I have the following method in a Vuejs app in a service module:

```
static async tenantsByRoles(roles) {
    const promises = [];
    roles.forEach((role) => {
      promises.push(this.fetch(role.tenantCode));
    });
    const tenants = await Promise.all(promises);
    return tenants.map(tenant => new Tenant(tenant.data));
  }
```

What I need to do is catch any errors, in particular any calls to `this.fetch(role.tenantCode))`:

```
static async fetch(tenantCode) {
    return await super.perform(axios.get(ServiceUrlProvider.myUrl().concat('/tenant/').concat(tenantCode)));
  }
```

because some of them will be 404s (unfortunately something beyond my control).

I modified like so to attach a `.catch()` method to `Promise.all()`

```
static async tenantsByRoles(roles) {
    const promises = [];
    roles.forEach((role) => {
      promises.push(this.fetch(role.tenantCode));
    });
    const tenants = await Promise.all(promises)
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    return tenants.map(tenant => new Tenant(tenant.data));
  }
```

but nothing is caught by the `.catch()`. What I want to do is catch the errors thrown by the 404s and suppress them. From what I've read, I'm doing the `catch()` correctly, but it's not working.

I've also tried resolving the promises individually,with something like so

```
static async tenantsByRoles(roles) {
    const promises = [];
    roles.forEach((role) => {
      promises.push(this.fetch(role.tenantCode));
    });
    const tenants = [];
    promises.forEach((promise) => {
      const resolved = Promise.resolve();
    });
    // const tenants = await Promise.all(promises);
    return tenants.map(tenant => new Tenant(tenant.data));
  }
```

but I'm not sure what to pass to `resolve()` in this case. This is my first time getting into promises this in depth, so I'm trying to get this all figured out.

Comment: `Promise.all()` rejects when the first Promise in the array rejects. If you want to suppress rejected Promises, you need to attach the `.catch()` block to each Promise before it is pushed onto the array.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to await for your promises in the fetch method. It can return promises (I'm guessing super.perform() is a promise), that will be awaited by Promise.all().

```
static fetch(tenantCode) {
    return super.perform(axios.get(ServiceUrlProvider.myUrl().concat('/tenant/').concat(tenantCode)));
}
```

Then in order to catch any errors, either corresponding to the asynchronous nature of your function or synchrones javascript error, you can simply use try/catch. Being able to catch the asynchronous errors with this syntax is one of the many advantages of the async/await syntax.

```
static async tenantsByRoles(roles) {
    try {
        const promises = roles.map((role) => {
            return this.fetch(role.tenantCode)
        });
        const tenants = await Promise.all(promises);
        return tenants.map(tenant => new Tenant(tenant.data));
    } catch (e) {
       //handle your error here
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```